# How to set current value in collection in simple_form (using mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, simple-form

I have this in my form:

```
= f.input :location_id, :collection => @locations, :include_blank => false, :selected => @video.location
```

This works fine for my "new" view/action and I see a nice list of locations to choose from.

However when in my edit view, instead of seeing the list of locations, I just see an input field as if it is a string, like so:

```
Location: 4ebbc0f8e0ed180e91000002
```

Any ideas why I don't see my collection?

EDIT:

Figured it out, I had to do:

```
= f.input :location_id, :collection => @locations, :include_blank => false, :selected => @video.location.id
```

Also, I forgot to pass @locations in my edit controller, woops :)

Comment: it's better to answer yourself directly instead of edit your question.

Comment: Answer yourself is a great idea...

Comment: @user341458 - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the edited question body, in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Figured it out, I had to do:
>
> ```
> = f.input :location_id, :collection => @locations, :include_blank => false, :selected => @video.location.id
> ```
>
> Also, I forgot to pass @locations in my edit controller, whoops :)

~ answer per [user341458](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341458/user341458)